# Eslint won't respect custom settings of .eslintrc.json

Tags: json, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I want to use tab indention instead of spaces while using Airbnb settings in eslint. I have created the .eslintrc.json file using eslint --init in the root of my project

Problem is eslint won't respect the custom settings of this file.

I still get error:

```
[eslint] Unexpected tab character. (no-tabs)
```

The error is the same in VS Code, Vim, Sublime.

What am I missing here? According to what I read, this new .eslintrc.json file should work with my custom settings.

.eslintrc.json file:

```
   {
        "extends": "airbnb-base",
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "node": true
        },
        "rules": {
            "comma-dangle": "off",
            "indent": ["error", "tab"],
            "no-console": "off"
        }
    }
```

I first installed eslint globally and locally

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "comma-dangle": "off",
        "indent": ["error", "tab"],
        "no-tabs": 0,
        "no-console": "off"
    }
}
```

Needed no-tabs: 0